# How did I get ruby 1.9.x on Lion (OSX)

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, installation

I had been fooling around with rails, and somehow had ruby version 1.9 something and rails 3.2 installed.  I am sure don't recall installing them, but they were there, along with git and hg.

I just did a fresh install of Lion and the ruby version is only 1.8.7, and rails does not seem to be installed.

I did have Xcode installed before.  Would Xcode have upgraded my ruby version? All the instructions I have found on the web suggest using ruby-build or rvm.  But I don't recall using those last time ...

Am I losing my mind?

Does Xcode 4.3 include git?

~S

Comment: Did you ever run [`port`](http://www.macports.org/) or [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you had a 1.9 build with Rails before, but I'm fairly certain they don't come on OSX by default.

If you've installed Xcode 4.3, you might end up having some issues when trying to install some older builds of Ruby. Regardless, you're going to want to install the command-line tools from Xcode before installing a new ruby. I would highly recommend you use RVM, even if you didn't use it before. It just makes things a lot cleaner.

If you want to install any ruby versions <1.9.3, you'll want to read this blog post: http://jfire.io/blog/2012/03/02/xcode-4-dot-3-homebrew-and-ruby/

^
Do note that the above link assumes you have homebrew installed.

Hope I was of some help.

Comment: I am looking at my backup and I found a directory called .bundler.  I bet I used bundler to install it. Would you recommend RVM over RBENV?

Comment: rbenv is a bit more lightweight than RVM. You can use it to manage ruby versions, but can't really install them through it. I personally prefer RVM, but haven't really given rbenv a fair go myself.

Comment: this is what I did last night: install homebrew, brew install rbenv, brew install ruby-build, rbenv install 1.9.3.